# maven-jaxb2-plugin: how to accomplish this xjc command-line in the pom.xml?

Tags: maven, jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

Because of various issues with the XSDs I need to compile (described in other SO posts), I have a bindings file and also a local extension schema.  The following command line works correctly, but I'm having trouble figuring out the right `pom.xml` configuration to mimic this:

```
xjc -nv src/main/resources/TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd src/main/resources/local/ObaCcLocationReport.xsd -b src/main/resources/local/rename.xjb -d target
```

Mainly, how do I specify more than one XSD?  I tried:

```
<schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
<schemaIncludes>
  <include>TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd</include>
  <include>local/ObaCcLocationReport.xsd</include>
</schemaIncludes>
```

but it seemed to ignore the second `include`.

I also tried variations on:

```
<schema>
  <fileset>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd</include>
      <include>local/ObaCcLocationReport.xsd</include>
    </includes>
  </fileset>
</schema>
```

without success.  Suggestions?

**EDIT**

This works as a workaround, but it's not ideal:

Since `ObaCcLocationReport.xsd` depends on schemas that get compiled as part of `TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd`, I just had to make sure it got compiled *after* that, and it seems to process files in filepath order.  So I put the `ObaCcLocationReport.xsd` into an `x` subfolder and changed the `pom.xml` to:

```
<schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
<schemaIncludes>
  <include>TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd</include>
  <include>x/ObaCcLocationReport.xsd</include>
</schemaIncludes>
```

This compiled the schemas and generated the Java files correctly.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the [maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin).

So your compilation depends on the order of the schema files in the XJC command? Hm, interesting. Why?

Please post `mvn -X clean generate-sources` log in such cases.

It really seems that Maven does not maintain the order of the file patterns as I also get:

```
schemas=[file:/.../src/main/resources/local/ObaCcLocationReport.xsd,
         file:/.../src/main/resources/TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd]
```

Which is not what you want. Can be fixed, please [file an issue](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues). (I rely on one of the Maven libraries here, but can do it differently to maintain the order.)

You can configure it as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <strict>false</strict>
                <schemaIncludes/>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <fileset>
                            <includes>
                                <include>TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </schema>
                    <schema>
                        <fileset>
                            <includes>
                                <include>local/ObaCcLocationReport.xsd</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Gives you:

```
schemas=[file:/.../src/main/resources/TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd,
         file:/.../src/main/resources/local/ObaCcLocationReport.xsd]
```

Notes:

- Don't forget `<schemaIncludes/>` otherwise `src/main/resources/*.xsd` will be included by default.
- `<strict>false</strict>` gives you `-nv`.
- You can always do `args`/`arg` to configure `xjc` on the low level, but I won't recommend it.

Comment: No, sorry, I wasn't clear: it seemed to be processing them in filesystem order, *ignoring* the order they were presented in the `pom.xml`.  I'll try the completely-separate `<schema>` elements, thanks.

Comment: `<strict>` is not recognized. Has this changed?